# Parameter the property used to filter an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two functions that are almost same except that they compare different properties on the object inside an array. Is there a way to make that property as parameter and then combine these two functions into one?

First function, that compares property `credit` on the transactions array.

```
  public filterByCredit(filter: string) {

    switch (filter) {
      case 'Non-blanks':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx.credit);
        break;
      case 'Blanks':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => !tx.credit);
        break;
      case '> 500':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx.credit > 500);
        break;
    }

  }
```

Second function that compares property `debit`

```
public filterByDebit(filter: string) {
    switch (filter) {
      case 'Non-blanks':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx.debit);
        break;
      case 'Blanks':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => !tx.debit);
        break;
      case '> 500':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx.debit > 500);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.
Add one more parameter to the function which accepts the type that is `credit` or `debit`. Then inside the function set a variable depend on credit or debit

```
public filterByType(filter: string,type:string) {
  let __tp
  if(type==='credit'){
    __tp='credit'
  }
  else{
    __tp='debit'
  }
    switch (filter) {
      case 'Non-blanks':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx[__tp]);
        break;
      case 'Blanks':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => !tx[__tp]);
        break;
      case '> 500':
        this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx[__tp] > 500);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't pass the type directly instead of testing it ? `tx[type]` would be enough

Comment: @Zooly:  I guess the idea would be to do a safe check to access only "credit" or "debit" even if some incorrect argument is passed. But yeah, if it's incorrect anyway its incorrect.! Depends on how we want to build the app.

Comment: Ok I see your point. But in case of other value, `tp` will be undefined, so filter will be instable. Thanks to TypeScript types, it mays not compile?

Comment: @Zooly: Its an `else` so there will always be a value. And yeah typescript will be helpful.  :D (But not in runtime)

Comment: Oops missed the else statement! So yeah, subjective assign, but working and safe in a certain way :)

Comment: thanks for the hints on the safe check, I went with `if(key === 'credit' || key === 'debit'){//do stuff} else {//error log}`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a `key` parameter and use it as an accessor to your object property.

```
public filterByDebit(filter: string, key: string) {
    switch (filter) {
        case 'Non-blanks':
            this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx[key]);
            break;
        case 'Blanks':
            this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => !tx[key]);
            break;
        case '> 500':
            this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx[key] > 500);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just send another param:

```
public filterByCredetDebit(filter, creditOrDebit) {
    switch (filter) {
        case 'Non-blanks':
            this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx[creditOrDebit]);
            break;
        case 'Blanks':
            this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => !tx[creditOrDebit]);
            break;
        case '> 500':
            this.filteredTxs = this.localTransactions.filter(tx => tx[creditOrDebit] > 500);
            break;
    }
}
```